# Is there a good report for jest test case?

Tags: jestjs

I am using `jest` to test my reactjs application. It works fine but `jest` doesn't give me a good report about test case results. The output of `jest` shows each test suite followed by its output. I have more than 50 test suites and it is hard for me to scroll up to check each failed test cases. Is there a brief `jest` report which printing a brief summary about the whole test cases? 
below is my `jest.conf` file:

```
{
  "testRegex": "/tests/.*\\.test\\.jsx?$",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "roots": ["./src"],
  "coverageReporters": ["text-summary", "html"]
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is also a JEST HTML Reporter module which you might find useful.
It's configurable to specify what level of detail you want to show in the test report for failures

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-html-reporter

Answer (score 15):

You can run jest with the `--coverage` flag.

If you want something different than the default reporters, you have to set them in your jest config file.

**jest.json**

```
{
  "coverageReporters": ["text-summary", "html"]
}
```

`text-summary` gives you a short summary beneath all tests that tells you how many suites/tests are successful/failed.

`html` gives you a some html pages that you can browse through to see exactly what got tested.

**CLI**

`$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest --config ./path/to/jest.json --coverage`

You might want to adjust which files are covered etc.
See all coverage options in the [jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#collectcoverage-boolean).

Comment: I have tried this option but it doesn't show the report. I have posted my jest.conf file.

Comment: I see you have added the `roots` option. This may influence the results. Try adding the `collectCoverageFrom` option and maybe one of the other *coverage* options. On a sidenote, it's usually better to keep your "roots" relative to `rootDir`, [using "<rootDir>"](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#rootdir-string)

Comment: collectCoverageFrom doesn't help, because it measures code coverage, not test suite report measurement asked by this question.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/jest-community/awesome-jest#reporters contains a list of other reporters.  `jest-stare` will let you filter off passing tests so you can just see the ones that failed.

Answer (score 8):

Use Istanbul to generate Reports

In the Script section of the Package.json just add :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
  }
```

Save the project and run below command:

Yarn test : For Terminal Coverage

Yarn test-coverage for Report Generation.Find HTML report in Coverage > Icov-report >index.html

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you can use a web-based reporter try [Tesults](https://www.tesults.com) - a reporter for Jest is available to help with integration: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-tesults-reporter.

You main issue, with respect to navigating test suites is handled well. I should add a disclaimer that I work at Tesults, but on the other hand if this is for a very small team or it's open source it is free to use, just contact support.

Comment: it's not a (pay) online service? it seems ot